GraalVM cannot find BouncyCastle provider
I've got a Clojure program that I am trying to compile into a native image using GraalVM. The program is just a main function:
(defn -main [& args]
  (println (Signature/getInstance "EDDSA" (Security/getProvider "BC"))))

I compile it into a native image and I get this when I run it:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing provider
    at java.base@11.0.20/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:96)
    at java.base@11.0.20/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:218)
    at java.base@11.0.20/java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:450)
    at company.cli.release$_main.invokeStatic(release.clj:8)
    at company.cli.release$_main.doInvoke(release.clj:7)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at company.cli.release.main(Unknown Source)

If compiled it with -H:+TraceSecurityService switch and bouncy castle doesn't appear anywhere. I don't understand why it's not picked up. In the report I can see:
Service factory method java.security.Signature.getInstance(java.lang.String, java.security.Provider) is reachable.
    Analysis parsing context: 
        at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:441)
        at company.cli.release$_main.invokeStatic(release.clj:8)
        at company.cli.release$_main.doInvoke(release.clj:7)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at company.cli.release.main(Unknown Source)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.runCore0(JavaMainWrapper.java:180)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.runCore(JavaMainWrapper.java:137)
    Reachability of Signature service type API triggers registration of following services:


So the reachability detects this code. But the Signature services registered don't include any BouncyCastle algorithms.
Also if I change the code to:
(defn -main [& args]
  (println (Signature/getInstance "EDDSA" (BouncyCastleProvider.))))

the report is the same when running I get a different exception with same stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: EDDSA for provider BC

This code works if run normally via java command.
I have also tried:
(defn -main [& args]
  (Security/addProvider (BouncyCastleProvider.))
  (println (Signature/getInstance "EDDSA" (BouncyCastleProvider.))))

and
(defn -main [& args]
  (Security/addProvider (BouncyCastleProvider.))
  (println (Signature/getInstance "EDDSA" (Security/getProvider "BC"))))

With same result. I tried adding option -H:AdditionalSecurityProviders=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.
and I get one of the two errors above and the security services automatic registration report still lacks any mention of BouncyCastle
Why doesn't it add BC to providers?

It seems you need to provide extra info because of reflection or some other info not available at compile time unless it's provided.
This repo and this bug seem to contain relevant info for a Java project, which should be easy to include in a Clojure project.
